# Python multiprocessing: share immutable dict of constant value

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

## Goal

I wish to send a large `dict` of the following type to all python multiprocesses.

### Type

```py
thesaurus: Dict[str, Tuple[str, ...]] = {}
```

*Obviously, the value of `thesaurus` is set elsewhere, but is completely determined before multiprocessing.*

- None of the forked processes mutate the `thesaurus`, they only refer to it for their calculations.
- Importantly, `thesaurus` is very large, so sending it to child processes as a variable again and again makes no sense. The actual iterable *variable* sent to multiprocessing is pretty small.

### NB

- The code is tested *successfully* by passing `thesaurus` (reduced size) as a variable.
- I'm using `multiprocessing.Pool().map_async` function for calculations.

### Gist of tested code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8; mode: python3 -*-
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
from typing import Dict, Tuple

thesaurus: Dict[str, Tuple[str, ...]] = {}
my_iter: Dict[str, str] = {}

# populate thesaurus
thesaurus['s_1'] = ('a', 's', 'd', 'f')
thesaurus['s_2'] = ('q', 'w', 'e')
thesaurus['s_3'] = ('a', 'q')
my_iter['id_1'] = 'asdf'
my_iter['id_2'] = 'qwerty'


def _worker(args) -> Tuple[str, Tuple[str, ...]]:
    m_thesaurus = args[0]
    some_id: str = args[1]
    var: str = args[2]
    worker_res = tuple((key
                        for key, val in m_thesaurus.items()
                        if any(s in var for s in val)))
    return some_id, worker_res


with mp.Pool(len(os.sched_getaffinity(0)) - 1 or 1) as pool:
    res_map = pool.map_async(_worker,
                             ((thesaurus, s_id, var)
                              for s_id, var in my_iter.items()))
    mapped_dicts = dict(res_map.get())

print(mapped_dicts)
```

##### Results

```
{'id_1': ('s_1', 's_3'), 'id_2': ('s_2', 's_3')}
```

## Attempt

Since `multiprocessing.SharedMemoryManager()` supports `ShareableList` but no `dict` counterpart, I tried creating two `ShareableList` objects from `thesaurus.keys()` and `thesaurus.values()`, planning to iterate over them `zipped` inside the worker. `ShareableList` of `thesaurus.keys()` got created successfully.

### Failure

However, `ShareableList` of `thesaurus.values()` can't be created, since it is a nested `Iterable`.

#### Attempted code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8; mode: python3 -*-
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.managers import SharedMemoryManager
from typing import Dict, Tuple

thesaurus: Dict[str, Tuple[str, ...]] = {}
my_iter: Dict[str, str] = {}

# populate thesaurus
thesaurus['s_1'] = ('a', 's', 'd', 'f')
thesaurus['s_2'] = ('q', 'w', 'e')
thesaurus['s_3'] = ('a', 'q')
my_iter['id_1'] = 'asdf'
my_iter['id_2'] = 'qwerty'


def _worker(args) -> Tuple[str, Tuple[str, ...]]:
    m_keys: Tuple[str, ...] = args[0]
    m_vals: Tuple[Tuple[str, ...], ...] = args[1]
    some_id: str = args[2]
    var: str = args[3]
    worker_res = tuple((key
                        for key, val in zip(m_keys, m_vals)
                        if any(s in var for s in val)))
    return some_id, worker_res


with SharedMemoryManager() as smm:
    t_keys = smm.ShareableList(tuple(thesaurus.keys()))
    t_values = smm.ShareableList(tuple(thesaurus.values()))
    with mp.Pool(len(os.sched_getaffinity(0)) - 1 or 1) as pool:
        res_map = pool.map_async(_worker,
                                 ((t_keys, t_values, s_id, var)
                                  for s_id, var in my_iter.items()))
        mapped_dicts = dict(res_map.get())

print(mapped_dicts)
```

##### Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pradyumna/./test_shared_multi_dict.py", line 32, in <module>
    t_values = smm.ShareableList(tuple(thesaurus.values()))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 1372, in ShareableList
    sl = shared_memory.ShareableList(sequence)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py", line 298, in __init__
    _formats = [
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py", line 299, in <listcomp>
    self._types_mapping[type(item)]
KeyError: <class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Multiprocessing makes entirely separate processes. They can not share memory

Comment: Just go to the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: I've clarified my idea by editing the question.
@mousetail, the link shared by @BeardOverflow appears to suggest otherwise.

@BeardOverflow, I'm pretty new to this. could you elaborate on passing the `dict` object?

Comment: Also, I guess I don't necessarily want a shared memory (although, that may have added benifit of saved space). I primarily want to preset constants in the multiprocesses.